# Pushing data from salesforce org to PHP server

Tags: api, integration, php

Is it possible to publish data from one salesforce to PHP apart from using outbound messages(as it cant send the attachments). I have a requirement where the website built on PHP has to be updated according to the data updated in salesforce.

I am able to integrate PHP using toolkit(SOAP API) and Restful (Oauth settings). But both of these methods need an API user. As I need to establish one way integration (similar to outbound message, but capable of sending attachments (like images and PDF's too) without having to use a salesforce licensed user.

Any pointer will be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a callout from Salesforce to your PHP application. In this way Salesforce can actively send information to a secondary system. Check out the callout section in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts).

Keep in mind that you cannot do a call out from a trigger, so you'd have to use future methods (or preferably the Queueable interface), or another asynchronous method. There are plenty of options to solve this with Apex, check out the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com).

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding and taking in consideration the information from this trailhead module https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_intermediate/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

It says "Because platform security is a first-class Salesforce citizen, your web service requires authentication. In addition to the Apex class WSDL, external applications must use either the Enterprise WSDL or the Partner WSDL for login functionality."

This means than unfortunately to use the API from a external system you do required user authentication in order to bring a valid session ID to the API.

I hope it helps.